# jScrollPane не отображается сам скролл

Tags: html, css, jscrollpane

Всем привет.
Прикручиваю к `div` плагин `jScrollPane`. Блок `jScrollPane` создается, но сама полоса прокрутки не появляется.
CSS:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#chat').jScrollPane();});
```

```css
    #chat {
    width: 325px;
    height: 260px;
    border:  1px solid #999999;
    overflow-y: auto;}

    .chat_box{
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 255px;}


    .scroll{
    width: 335px;
    height: 270px;}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
               <div id="chat">
                    <div class="chat_box" contenteditable="true">

                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Может попробовать так?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chat').jScrollPane();
});
```

И в CSS:

```
overflow: auto;
```

вместо:

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

**UPD:**

У вас все правильно, но этот плагин работает [только для содержимого обернутого в тег](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/FFjgc/5/) `<p>`.

Удалите из примера все  параграфы `<p>` и полосы не появятся.

Также можно попробовать такую инициализацию:

```
$(window).load(function) {
  $("#chat").jScrollPane();
}
```

Еще один вариант инициализации:

```
$("#chat").jScrollPane({ autoReinitialise: true })
```

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: нет, не подходит. На странице висит еще 1 скрипт и скролл будет виден только после него  
`function changeStyleDiv(){
    document.getElementById('thanks').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('forms').style.display  = 'none';
}
`

Comment: Но даже если этот скрипт убрать то скроллы не отображаются.

Comment: А все понял. Этот плагин работет только для того что обернуто в тег <p>.

Comment: Нее, у меня на другой странице он работает без <p> а на этой, отказывается скролл бар показывать.

Comment: @Роман В load поробуй еще запихнуть инициализацию. Больше нет пока вариантов почему его не показывает.

Comment: `$("#chat").jScrollPane({ autoReinitialise: true })`  
скролл появился, но он постоянно дергается и совершенно не контролируется. Если посмотреть через F12 то `<div> ` ,блоки где он прописан постоянно мигают.

Comment: Значит там динамически элементы внутри обновляются слишком часто. Вот этот туториал посмотри: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_content.html чтобы вручную реиницализировать после каждого добавления.